# Java script for end date greater than start date

Tags: javascript, validation, date

i need a java script to validate **end_date** greater than **start_date**. I have found jquery to fulfill the process. Since it disables all the date before the selected start date, my Boss told it should not be used as the clients will ask all the previous pages in the same manner. So pls help on this by providing any working example or redirect me to correct link if this is a duplicate question.

Comment: Please reword your question - it is incomprehensible.

Comment: see this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135433/javascript-check-end-date-is-greater-than-or-equal-to-start-date

Comment: I've removed the [tag:c#] tags, because they didn't make sense.

Comment: i went for this. it is not accepted.
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Answer (score 1):

```js
 $('#btnsave').click(function () {
            var startDate = new Date($('#Sdate').val());
            var endDate = new Date($('#Edate').val());

            if (startDate > endDate) {
                alert("Start date is before end date!");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
```