# Make the current select menu hidden and and show the hidden input above it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating dynamic inputs to the form using javascript. I am having a problem is that when someone select the dropdown to no then the hidden element should be shown with required attr and the current select dropdown should be hidden.So far this is my code:

```
    <div id="work">
                <div class="form boxed ">
                    <a href="#" class="close-form remove-box button"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                    <input class="search-field" type="text" placeholder="Job Title" maxlength="100" />
                    <input class="search-field" type="text" placeholder="Company Name" maxlength="255" />
                    <input class="search-field" type="text" placeholder="Location" value=""/>
                    <input type="text" class="datepicker-here" data-language="en" data-min-view="months" data-view="months" data-date-format="MM yyyy" placeholder="Enter Start Date" />
                    <input type="text" class="datepicker-here" data-language="en" data-min-view="months" data-view="months" data-date-format="MM yyyy"  placeholder="Enter End Date" style="display: none" />

                    <label>Are you still working ?</label>
                    <select style="padding: 12px" required onchange="yesnoCheck(this);">
                        <option value="">Select Option</option>
                        <option value="Present">Yes</option>
                        <option value="No">No</option>
                    </select>


                </div>          
            </div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="addInput2('work');" class="button gray "><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add More</a>
```

this is the javascript function which is creating dynamic inputs:

```
function addInput2(divName){
     var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
     newdiv.innerHTML = "<div class='form boxed '>
         <a href='#' class='close-form remove-box button'><i class='fa fa-close'></i></a>
         <input class='search-field' type='text' placeholder='Job Title' value=''  maxlength='100' />
         <input class='search-field' type='text' placeholder='Company Name' maxlength='255' />
         <input class='search-field' type='text' placeholder='Location' value=''/>
         <input type='text' class='datepicker-here' data-language='en' data-min-view='months' data-view='months' data-date-format='MM yyyy' placeholder='Enter Start Date' />
         <input type='text' class='datepicker-here' data-language='en' data-min-view='months' data-view='months' data-date-format='MM yyyy' style='display: none'  placeholder='Enter End Date' />
         <label>Are you still working ?</label>
         <select style='padding: 12px' required onchange=''>
              <option value=''>Select Option</option>
              <option value='Present'>Yes</option>
              <option value='No'>No</option>
         </select>
</div>";

document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
}
```

This is the function which should do the work, so far i am able to get the current selected value

```
function yesnoCheck(that) {
        if (that.value == "No") {

        } else {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want to do, but you can clone that easier by loading the element in to a variable on page load. https://jsfiddle.net/fkc5r3jg/

Answer (score 1):

First, you will need to uniquely identify each occurrence of the `select` and hidden `input`, so that you can interact with them.

For that reason, I put a variable `jubNum` outside the `addInput2()` function, and increment it each time the function is called.  Using this variable, you can assign unique `id`'s to the elements which need to interact with each other.

Once you can uniquely identify the `select` in question, and the `input` in question, you can use `display = block` to show the `input`, and `required = true` to give it the `required` attribute.

```js
var jobNum = 1;
function addInput2(divName){
     var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
     newdiv.innerHTML = "<div class='form boxed'><a href='#' class='close-form remove-box button'><i class='fa fa-close'></i></a><input class='search-field' type='text' placeholder='Job Title' value=''  maxlength='100' /> <input class='search-field' type='text' placeholder='Company Name' maxlength='255' /><input class='search-field' type='text' placeholder='Location' value=''/><input type='text' class='datepicker-here' data-language='en' data-min-view='months' data-view='months' data-date-format='MM yyyy' placeholder='Enter Start Date' /><input id='job"+jobNum+"end' type='text' class='datepicker-here' data-language='en' data-min-view='months' data-view='months' data-date-format='MM yyyy' style='display: none'  placeholder='Enter End Date' /><label>Are you still working ?</label><select id='job"+jobNum+"' style='padding: 12px' required onchange='yesnoCheck(this);'><option value=''>Select Option</option><option value='Present'>Yes</option><option value='No'>No</option></select></div>";

jobNum++;

document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
}


function yesnoCheck(that) {
        if (that.value == "No") {
          document.getElementById(that.id + 'end').style.display = 'block';
          document.getElementById(that.id + 'end').required = true;
        } else {
          document.getElementById(that.id + 'end').style.display = 'none';
          document.getElementById(that.id + 'end').required = false;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div id="work">
                <div class="form boxed">
                    <a href="#" class="close-form remove-box button"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                    <input class="search-field" type="text" placeholder="Job Title" maxlength="100" />
                    <input class="search-field" type="text" placeholder="Company Name" maxlength="255" />
                    <input class="search-field" type="text" placeholder="Location" value=""/>
                    <input type="text" class="datepicker-here" data-language="en" data-min-view="months" data-view="months" data-date-format="MM yyyy" placeholder="Enter Start Date" />
                    <input id="job0end" type="text" class="datepicker-here" data-language="en" data-min-view="months" data-view="months" data-date-format="MM yyyy"  placeholder="Enter End Date" style="display: none" />

                    <label class="no">Are you still working ?</label>
                    <select id="job0" class="noo" style="padding: 12px" required onchange="yesnoCheck(this);">
                        <option value="">Select Option</option>
                        <option value="Present">Yes</option>
                        <option value="No">No</option>
                    </select>


                </div>          
            </div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="addInput2('work');" class="button gray "><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add More</a>
```

Comment: thanks it's working great but how to hide the current select element and also to check the end date should be greater than start date.

Comment: From a UX perspective, are you sure you want to hide the `select` element?  This would mean that if a user selects 'Yes' by mistake, they cannot go back and select 'No' because the `select` is hidden.

Comment: that would not be good i guess, just check the date difference would do the work. Thanks

Comment: You can check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135433/javascript-check-end-date-is-greater-than-or-equal-to-start-date, but ultimately it would depend on what you will use for the datepicker.  I believe that's a separate question.

Comment: Glad it works for you :)  If you have another question, just post again!